# Logic Error in World Series Program

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files, python-3.4, for-in-loop

This is the assignment:

> "In the module is the file WorldSeriesWinners.txt. This file contains
>   a chronological list of the World Series winning teams from 1903
>   through 2009. (The first line in the file is the name of the team that
>   won in 1903, and the last line is the name of the team that won in
>   2009).
>
> Write a program that lets the user enter the name of a team and then
>   displays the number of times that team has won the World Series in the
>   time period from 1903 through 2009.
>
> The program is required to use a list to read in the data and for in
>   loop for counting the times won."

The program should look like this:

```
Enter the name of a team: Chicago Cubs
The Chicago Cubs won the world series 2 times between 1903 and 2009.
=============================== RESTART ============================
Enter the name of a team: New York Yankees
The New York Yankees won the world series 26 times between 1903 and 2009.
=============================== RESTART ============================
Enter the name of a team: Lakeland Tigers
The Lakeland Tigers never won the world series.
=============================== RESTART ============================
```

I think I'm pretty close to solving the problem, save for one logic error.

This is my code:

```
# Write a program that lets the user enter the name of a team
# and then displays the number of times that team had won the World Series
# in the time period from 1903 to 2009

# Open the file
def main():
    infile = open('WorldSeriesWinners.txt', 'r') # Open the file

    winner = infile.readlines() # Read the contents of the file into the list

    infile.close() # Always remember to close the file

    team = input('Enter the name of a team: ') # Enter name of a baseball team

    counter = 0 # If said team won a game, count how many times
    for team in winner:
            result = counter + 1

    if result == 1: # Finally, print the results
        print("The", team, "won the world series", result, "time between 1903 and 2009.")
    elif result > 1:
        print("The", team, "won the world series", result, "times between 1903 and 2009.")
    else:
        print("The", team, "never won the world series.")

main()
```

And this is what happens when I press F5:

```
>>> 
Enter the name of a team: Chicago Cubs
The Philadelphia Phillies won the world series 1 time between 1903 and 2009.
>>>
```

Two things: Not only did I NOT type in the Philadelphia Phillies, but the count is incorrect because the Phillies won the World Series twice (1980 and 2008), and thus the team's name appears twice in the text file (and yes, I checked to make sure).

Answer (score 3):

That is because you are not counting the team input by the user, you are just looping over the teams and counting 1 for each team. Also, your `counter` is always 0, and adding 1 to it will always result in 1. You need to increment it each time a team has won, which means you have to keep track of what the current number of wins is, which means you have to change the value of `counter` to actually count the number of wins a team has. What you need is:

```
for winning in winner:
    if(team == winning):
        counter += 1
```

That should give you the answer. And you don't need `result` anymore.

---

Ps. Here is a genuine advice, this is an assignment for a class. Asking for a solution on SO will answer your assignment and earn you the grade, but you will only learn to copy-paste in your life, and not solve the problem. Please, do everything you can to solve it yourself first.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I feel bad about that, actually. I'm still new to programming, and while I feel I have a fairly good grasp of the terms and concepts, putting it into practice can sometimes completely boggle my mind. I looked at past assignments and was able to get closer to this particular problem, but remember how to format these counting loops was completely lost on me for some reason, even though I *have* done it before.

Comment: There is something called a [dry run](http://theteacher.info/websites/ocr_alevel/WebPages/F452_ProgTechn/DryRuns/DryRuns.html), practice that diligently. And teach yourself to use the debugger, and inspect variables as you run it line by line.

Comment: Thank you, @Kartik. BTW, I typed in the counter loop but it's still counting inaccurately. But I'll take your advice and try to solve this on my own.

Answer (score 2):

I have worked the other peoples answers into a complete piece of code

```
def main():
    infile = open('WorldSeriesWinners.txt', 'r') # Open the file

    winners = infile.readlines() # Read the contents of the file into the list

    infile.close() # Always remember to close the file

    team = input('Enter the name of a team: ') # Enter name of a baseball team

    counter = 0 # If said team won a game, count how many times

    for winner in winners:
        if team == winner:
            counter = counter + 1

    if counter == 1: # Finally, print the results
        print("The", team, "won the world series", counter, "time between 1903 and 2009.")
    elif counter > 1:
        print("The", team, "won the world series", counter, "times between 1903 and 2009.")
    else:
        print("The", team, "never won the world series.")

main()
```

The errors in your original program are:

- Count been incorrect

You were initialising `counter` with 0.  Then in the loop you are performing `counter + 1` then assigning it to `result`.  But each iteration of the loop did the same thing so the count would be 1.  You needed to reuse counter so it incremented on each iteration. (Changing this causes `result` to no longer to be needed so the rest of the program was updated accordingly with `counter`.)

You also need to comparing the text entered into the `team` variable to the loops variable.  Otherwise the count would have been the number of items in the file.

- Team name been incorrect

You reused the variable `team` in the for loop.

This was causing your second error the original team name was been overwrote so your originally entered value was no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have used two different variable names for the same concept, `counter` and `result`.If you stick to using one or the other variable names your program will work better.

Also your for loop logic is wrong here. You shouldn't reuse the variable name `team` (that is why your chosen team is ignored), and secondly you have to actually compare the loop variable with the chosen team:

```
result = 0
for test in winner:
    if team == test:
        result = result + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured out the biggest problem that no one on this thread pointed out: I had to *strip and split the lines!* When I printed the file in its original form, it was all one single block with a bunch of '\n' between each team. *That's* why it was counting incorrectly! So, when I used the stripped the '\n' and split the lines between each of the teams, my code was able to work. Also, I converted inputs into lowercase so as to make case-insensitive input.

And now, my solution:

```
# Write a program that lets the user enter the name of a team
# and then displays the number of times that team had won the World Series
# in the time period from 1903 to 2009

# Open the file
def main():
    infile = open('WorldSeriesWinners.txt', 'r') # Open the file

    for line in open('WorldSeriesWinners.txt'):
        line = line.rstrip('\n')# But wait, strip the newlines first!

    winners = infile.read().splitlines() # Read the contents of the file into the list

    infile.close() # Always remember to close the file

    team = input('Enter the name of a team: ') 

    counter = 0 # If said team won a game, count how many times

    for winner in winners: # convert input to lowercase for case-insensitive input
        if team.lower() == winner.lower():
            counter = counter + 1

    if counter == 1: # Finally, print the results
        print("The", team, "won the world series", counter, "time between 1903 and 2009.")
    elif counter > 1:
        print("The", team, "won the world series", counter, "times between 1903 and 2009.")
    else:
        print("The", team, "never won the world series.")


main()
```

The biggest lesson I learned was to print the file into Python first, and see if there's any potential problems with that!